# Can't paste form action in Composite C1

Tags: .net, c1-cms

I created an HTML form in a new page in C1, unfortunately when I paste the form action I got from the developer to send the form to another system, it complains about the '=' characters that are part of the value. Why is C1 listening to the values I have in a form? It prevents me from Saving the page so I can't move forward. Is there a way to disable this intrusive watching over your shoulder in C1?

Update: Composite C1 site says:

> **Important Notes**
>
> 1. If the template uses an HTML form, consider using Composite C1 addons that provide the same or similar functionality. You might need to use some forms within **<asp:form>** element.
> 2. Replace the encoded characters the literal type `(&nbsp; &copy;)` with their numerical equivalents `(&#160; &#169;)` to avoid validation errors in the template.

http://docs.composite.net/Layout/Artisteer-Templates

Does this mean we can't freely add html forms to new pages without having to use FormBuilder? which by the way is not free.

Comment: What is your form action? Usually its as simple as correctly encoding & as &amp;

Comment: //domainname.us8.list-manage.com/subscribe/post?u=83db3e233c543f13d883b60ba&id=b4a54151c4 I also tried to encode the "=" signs but it doesn't allow me to save the file. there is something about this string that the editor complains about

Comment: As I said, write & as &amp; and you're good.

Comment: Pauli the issue is not the ampersand is the equal signs as I stated above.

Comment: So you did replace the & with &amps; with no effect?

Comment: If you go to http://codebeautify.org/xmlviewer and paste in `<form action="//domainname.us8.list-manage.com/subscribe/post?u=83db3e233c543f13d883b60ba&id=b‌​4a54151c4"></form>` and press *Tree View* you'll get a error about EntityRef. If you correctly encode the & as &amp; you can press the *Tree View* and get a nice result without errors.